# HTML table in ADO Work Item description field

Tags: html, azure-devops, workitem, azure-boards

Is it possible to add an HTML table (or some other format that would create a table) in the description field of a work item? I have tried adding HTML in the description, but it just takes it as text and ignores the markup.

I am coming from Atlassian JIRA. While it did not recognize HTML, but it did have formatting that allowed creation of tables in description of comment field. Just wondering if ADO has some equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible via Rest API, i have tried creating user story using python and created a table in the description. the only problem i have now i that i cannot format the table to show the borders.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33717644)